# SSIS Execute SQL Stored Procedure output parameter type mismatch

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I'm getting the following error on an SSIS package:

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "EXEC [spGetFileId] @zFileName, @Id" failed with the following error: "The type of the value being assigned to variable "User::FileId" differs from the current variable type. Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object.

I have created an **Execute SQL Task** which executes a simple stored procedure on the SQL server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetFileId]
    @zFileName VARCHAR(255),
    @Id INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT  @Id = [Id]
    FROM    [tblFileLog]
    WHERE   [zFileName] = @zFileName
END
```

The **SQLStatement** property of the task is:

```
EXEC [spGetFileId] @zFileName, @Id
```

I have the following **SSIS variables**:

> - **User::File** (String)
> - **User::FileId** (Int)

and the parameters are mapped on the SQL task as follows:

> - Variable | Direction | Type | Parameter
> - **User::File** | Input | String | @zFileName
> - **User::FileId** | Output | Int32 | @Id

I've tried playing around with the variable types (`int16`, `int32` and `int64`; even string) but the error persists. Please help!

**EDIT:**

Debugging the stored procedure I added a `PRINT @Id` before the `END` and this outputs the expected value but when doing `SELECT @Id` (the output param) this returns `NULL`.

**EDIT2:**

A coworker has identified the problem and offered his solution which I have marked as answer below.

Comment: The mapping and naming of the parameters depends on the connection you are using. Could you please told us wich are you using (ADO, OLE DB, ADO.NET...)

Comment: The connection type for the SQL task is ADO.NET

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **SQLStatement** on the **Execute SQL Task** must include `OUTPUT` after the `@Id` parameter:

```
EXEC [spGetFileId] @zFileName, @Id OUTPUT
```

And you need to set your @User::FileID parameter an Output parameter to enable the variable as readwrite instead of readonly which lets it be written to.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an output parameter, use a result set, set ResultSet to "Single row" and map the result to your variable:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetFileId]
    @zFileName VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT  [Id]
    FROM    [tblFileLog]
    WHERE   [zFileName] = @zFileName
END
```

[image]

Comment: I don't dispute that this would probably work, but it would mean going against internal convention for our stored procedures. +1 for the workaround but I'm afraid I can't accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using an OLE DB connection for your Execute SQL Task and read this article - http://www.bidn.com/blogs/BillBrannen/bidn-blog/612/stored-procedure-return-values-and-output-parameters-in-ssis